# Jinja modify base.html depending on the page

Tags: html, templates, flask, jinja2, sidebar

I'm using jinja in the templates of my flask project.

My question is : how to change the color of one of the elements of the sidebar (which is in base.html file) when you are on the corresponding page ?

I mean let's say I have a sidebar with the following titles linked to their corresponding page : dashboard, feature1, feature2.

How can I do if I want feature1 to change of color when I am on feature1, then change back feature1 to its original color and turn dashboard to the selected color when I click and go on dashboard page ?

Because I don't really know how to simply do it instead of creating a new content in each of my pages' html template.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS class for the active link. This defines the style properties for the menu entry of the currently used page.

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

To add the class to the menu item, you can use a simple if condition using the request object. Here you can compare whether the current request is the same as the identifier of the endpoint.

```py
@app.route('/')
def dashboard():
    # ...
```

```html
<a 
    class="{% if request.endpoint == 'dashboard' %}active{% endif %}" 
    href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}"
>Dashboard</a>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot for your reply, I had not thought about simply use the request parameter to identify the corresponding page. It's perfect thank you ;)